# Template class generic specialization in separate cpp-file: many template arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Suppose in .h file I have a template class declaration:

```
template<typename T1, 
         typename T2, 
         typename T3,
         typename T4>
class A {
public:
  A();
  ~A();

  void method1();
  void method2();

  ...
}
```

The number of template arguments is subject of changing since this API
is still not fixed. I prefer to implement a generic specialization in separated .cpp file. As I understand one may write (e.g. for ctor):

```
template<typename T1, 
         typename T2, 
         typename T3,
         typename T4>
A<T1, T2, T3, T4>::A() {
   ...
}
```

and so on for each class A methods ... It annoyed me to use bulky construction:

```
template<typename T1, 
         typename T2, 
         typename T3,
         typename T4>
A<T1, T2, T3, T4>::
```

everytime I implement class A methods. In case of addition or deletion
of one or several template arguments it will be a big problem.
Can I use some C++ language feature (upto C++11) to avoid this? Early I saw a preprocessor macro to do this but it is ugly I think :)

Comment: `I prefer to implement a generic specialization in separated .cpp file` - The user of your template will have to also see this specialization to make template instantiation possible, so unless you are ready to explicitly instantiate versions of A in this .cpp, you may also put this implementation in .h file.

Comment: Variadic templates in c++11 could be used. Check http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/variadic-templates-in-c/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create an intermediate class to hold the template arguments.  Something like this.

A.h
    template
    class TemplateParams {
        using T1_S = T1;
        using T2_S = T2;
        using T3_S = T3;
        using T4_S = T4;
    };

```
template<typename TemplateParams>
class A_Base {
public:
  A_Base();
  ~A_Base();

  void method1();
  void method2();
};

template<typename T1, 
         typename T2, 
         typename T3,
         typename T4>
using A = A_Base<TemplateParams<T1,T2,T3,T4>>;

#include "A_impl.h"
```

A_impl.h

```
   template<typename TemplateParams>
   A_Base<TemplateParams>::A_Base() {}

   template<typename TemplateParams>
   A_Base<TemplateParams>::~A_Base() {}


    template<typename TemplateParams>
    void A_Base<TemplateParams>::method1() {

    }
```

No change in the way it is used

```
#include "A.h"
A<int,int,int,int> a;
a.method1();
```